# Making Scala choose less specific overloaded method in presence of argument of type Nothing

Tags: scala, overloading, thunk, bottom-type

If come across an interesting case with thunks versus functions in the presence of type `Nothing`:

```
object Test {
  def apply(thunk: => Any     ): String => Any = _ => thunk
  def apply(fun: String => Any): String => Any = fun
}

val res0 = Test { println("hello") }
res0("foo") // --> hello

val res1 = Test { x: String => println(s"hello $x") }
res1("foo") // --> hello foo

val res2 = Test { x: String => throw new RuntimeException("ex") }
util.Try(res2("foo")) // --> Failure

val res3 = Test { throw new RuntimeException("ex") } // boom!
```

Now the tricky bit is the last case. Is it possible to modify the `apply` method to make Scala choose the thunk version of it, instead of the `Function1` version (which is more specific and thus preferred, and **`Nothing <: Function1[_,_]`**, therefore...)

I tried to come up with low-high priority implicits and magnet pattern, but haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick draft of a type-safe approach based on type classes:

```
object Test {
  trait Wrap[A, B] { def apply(a: => A): String => B }

  trait LowWrap {
    implicit def thunkWrap[A] = new Wrap[A, A] { def apply(a: => A) = _ => a }
  }

  trait MidWrap extends LowWrap {
    implicit def funcWrap[A] = new Wrap[String => A, A] {
      def apply(f: => String => A) = f
    }
  }

  object Wrap extends MidWrap {
    implicit object nothingWrap extends Wrap[Nothing, Nothing] {
      def apply(f: => Nothing) = _ => f
    }
  }

  def apply[A, B](a: => A)(implicit w: Wrap[A, B]) = w(a)
}
```

And then:

```
scala> Test { println("hello") }
res0: String => Unit = <function1>

scala> res0("foo")
hello

scala> Test { x: String => println(s"hello $x") }
res2: String => Unit = <function1>

scala> res2("foo")
hello foo

scala> Test { x: String => throw new RuntimeException("ex") }
res4: String => Nothing = <function1>

scala> util.Try(res4("foo"))
res5: scala.util.Try[Nothing] = Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: ex)

scala> Test { throw new RuntimeException("ex") }
res6: String => Nothing = <function1>

scala> util.Try(res6("foo"))
res7: scala.util.Try[Nothing] = Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: ex)
```

You might be able to simplify a bit, add variance, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
val res3 = Test { (throw new RuntimeException("ex")): Any }
```

This works as expected. (No exception on creation, exception when calling `res3`).

Comment: Ok, but I think the idea is that the use site doesn't need to bother with fixing this, but the interface should automatically take care.

Answer (score 1):

A solution which uses reflection. (Still curious: can one write a static solution?)

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._

object Test {
  def apply[A: TypeTag](thunk: => A): String => Any =
    if (typeOf[A] =:= typeOf[Nothing]) // hah, caught you
      _ => thunk
    else if (typeOf[A] <:< typeOf[String => Any])
      thunk.asInstanceOf[String => Any]
    else
      _ => thunk
}

val res0 = Test { println("hello") }
res0("foo") // --> hello

val res1 = Test { x: String => println(s"hello $x") }
res1("foo") // --> hello foo

val res2 = Test { x: String => throw new RuntimeException("ex") }
util.Try(res2("foo")) // --> Failure

val res3 = Test { throw new RuntimeException("ex") }
util.Try(res3("foo")) // --> Failure
```

(a macro based version of this would be static, I guess)